# Is there a faster way to apply a function to all the strings within a multidimensional array than using foreach? (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here's my iteration:

```
foreach ($this->itens as $i => $i_val) {
    foreach ($i_val as $j => $j_val) {
        if (is_string($this->itens[$i]->$j)) {
            $this->itens[$i]->$j = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($this->itens[$i]->$j, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $this->itens[$i]->$j);
        }
    }
}
```

This running each time something is loaded from the Database is just too performance-killer, and it's quite necessary since the previous programmers screwed the database with multiple random encodings. Anyway, is there a faster way to perform this operation in PHP? A traditional while loop is faster than a foreach? Is there a function that can apply a function to all the inner contents, like map on Python or similar?

Comment: Why don't you normalize the DB data to begin with, instead of converting it each time you use it? Just a thought...

Answer (score 0):

I think http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php will do what you are after?

array_walk_recursive() is similar to array_walk(), applying your function, but does it in a multi-dimensional/recursive sense - basically it does what the name says!

As you've got a bit of logic in there, you'd have to write your own function that comprises the comparison and the resultant return value, and then pass that function to the array_walk_recursive() function (or depending on your PHP version, you could write it as an anonymous function):

```
$this->itens = array_walk_recursive($this->itens,function($param,$key){
    if (is_string($param)) {
        return iconv(mb_detect_encoding($param, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $param);
    }else{
        return $param;
    }
});
```

Comment: `array_walk_recursive` is almost certainly going to be slower, as it's allocating memory for a _copy_, iterating an array/object (like the OP is already doing), creating an instance of the `Closure` class _and_ replacing the `foreach` statements with a method call (which has a lot more overhead)

Comment: Unlike `array_map`, which returns the updated array, `array_walk_recursive` returns a boolean. So, `$this->itens` will have a boolean value at the end of the operation. Not what the OP wants.